# OpenGL: ModelView and Projection matrices

Tags: android, opengl-es, projection-matrix

I want to use gluUnProject for 3D picking. It returns wrong values. I think the reason is that ModelView & Projection matrices are generated incorrectly. To grab them, I use MatrixGrabber, MatrixStack and MatrixTrackingGL classes from API demos:

```java
MatrixGrabber mg = new MatrixGrabber();  
mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);  
mg.getCurrentModelView(gl);
```

Wherever I place the camera, Projection & ModelView matrices are the same all the way:

**ModelView**

```java
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0  
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

**Projection**

```java
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0  
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Some code:

```java
private Game game;
private final float boardSize = 25f;
private float[] eyeV;
private float[] centerV;
private float[] upV;
private GL10 gl;
private MatrixGrabber mg;
public GLRenderer() {
    game = new Game();
    eyeV = new float[] { boardSize / 2f, boardSize / 5f, boardSize * 1.2f };
    centerV = new float[] { boardSize / 2f, boardSize / 2f, 0f };
    upV = new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f };
    mg = new MatrixGrabber();
}
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    this.gl = gl;
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearColor(.2f, .2f, .2f, 1f);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    game.LoadTextures(gl);
}
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeV[0], eyeV[1], eyeV[2], centerV[0], centerV[1], centerV[2], upV[0], upV[1], upV[2]);
    game.draw(gl);
    mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);
    mg.getCurrentModelView(gl);
}
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / (float) height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 100);
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: OpenGL contexts are local to one single thread at a time, and in an android application, the renderer runs on a separate thread. So if you are trying to use the MatrixGrabber from the main Activity thread, it won't be able to get the matrix. Try using the matrix grabber at the end of onDrawFrame, and see if you still end up with identity matrices.